# Execute second WHERE condition only if first WHERE condition isn't satisfying

Tags: mysql, hive

I have a set of WHERE conditions and my requirement is condition2 should be executed only after condition1 isn't satisfied, below is my query

```
SELECT (B.col1, B.col2, B.col3)
FROM
(SELECT firstname, lastname FROM employee) A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM office) B
ON 
TRIM(A.firstname) = TRIM(B.col1) AND 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT col4, col5, col6 FROM school) C
ON
TRIM(A.firstname) = TRIM(C.col4) 
WHERE (condition1) OR (condition2) OR (condition3) OR (condition4) OR (condition5) OR (condition6);
```

Comment: That's how `OR` works. Once one condition is satisfied, there's no need to check any others.

Comment: MySQL uses short-circuit evaluation of logical operators.

Comment: You meant there is a better approach of doing this, because in my case condition1 and condition3 are satisfying resulting in 2 records, i want the execution to be stopped right after condition1 is satisfied

Comment: To be clear. You are saying you do not want the records matching condition2 or later if condition1 is met?

Comment: The conditions are evaluated separately for every row. If a row satisfies any of the conditions it will be returned.

Comment: @Uueerdo Do you think there is a better approach?

Comment: In that case, you'll need separate queries; it **can** be done in a single query, but would be extremely complicated and probably highly inefficient.

Comment: I agree with @Uueerdo. Use a loop where you perform the query with each condition, and as soon as you get a non-empty result exit from the loop.

Comment: @Barmar Did you mean to use a IF inside the WHERE? Can you give me a sample please?

Comment: This would be possible in a single query if you need only one row in the result set. Even multiple row result would be possible in some cases - But one would need to know the exact conditions.

Comment: @KiranKumar No, I meant do the loop in an application programming language that's performing the database queries.

Comment: Why not start with a simpler example

Answer (score -1):

You'll need separate queries. It can be done in a single query, but would be extremely complicated and probably highly inefficient. To give a succinct example of such a (horrible) query for reference:

```
SELECT [stuff]
FROM [stuff2: tables, joins, etc....]
WHERE [condition1]
   OR ([condition2] AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [stuff2... yes, copy everything from the first stuff2] WHERE [condition1]))
   OR ([condition3] AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [stuff2] WHERE [condition1] OR [condition2]))
   OR ([condition4] AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [stuff2] WHERE [condition1] OR [condition2] OR [condition3]))
   and so on...
```

So just query against each such condition separately until you get results or run out of conditions to check.